# Save JSON from Openlayers using AJAX

Tags: geojson, openlayers, php, ajax

I am trying to build a web app where users can use OpenLayers to draw features and then save them either as a download or write to a file on the server which I can collect when I need it. I am happy with the OL3 bit so far. 
From reading around it seems AJAX is the way to do this so I have managed to included a button in my HMTL which runs a function that runs a php file to create a new file.I was pretty happy that I managed to get an empty text file as a start. So how do I get that file to contain the JSON information? I assume I need to send it from the JS world to PHP somehow?

**The Function**

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET","run.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

**The button**

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">do something</button>
```

**The PHP file (run.php)**

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("store/anothernewfile.geojson", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = ['lyr_site'];
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

I don't have a geoserver and don't think it is really necessary for something simple like this, using .geojson files seems to be working so far.

Comment: think this is a more programming question than GIS? but would use a database to save the data with php like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467945/how-to-generate-json-file-with-php

Comment: I am trying to keep things simple so no geoserver and no databases. A nice person on stack overflow pointed me in the right direction. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483695/saving-json-data-using-ajax)

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: Yep - I put a link in my comment. I have it all working.